# Please help me understand the grammar of this にする sentence

Tags: grammar

This sentence appeared on NHK news web easy today in regards to the corona virus.

> 厚生労働省は、検査の結果が出るまで、外に出ないようにしてもらうことにしています。

I believe the grammar that is tripping me up is the nested にする in te form.

My best interpretation:

> According to some government office, until the results of the test are received, [they] won't be allowed to leave.

The ～ようにしてもらう　construction and the final ～もらうことにしています　Must be a type of grammatical construction I am not familiar with yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the subject of います　is the Ministry of Health (厚生労働省) whereas the subject of 出ない is people who have taken the medical tests.

Broken down:

The ministry of health (厚生労働省は) decides that (しています) it will receive [by the potentially ill people] the favor (もらうことに) of their making sure (して) to not go out 
(出ないように).